# Inline Javascript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've been just adding my individual scripts at the bottom of my rails views via script tags.

It just seems way easier and more intuitive to include a one off script in the actual view rather than a separate JS file. But what are the arguments against doing this?

Comment: A separate file can be minified and cached by the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the script in a separate file, you can:

1. Include it in as many pages you want
2. Have it pre-processed and minified in production
3. Declare depedencies between modules
4. Lint it using tools like [jshint](http://jshint.com/)
5. Test it, having one test file per source